# Java -- How to make a continous counter (1 + 2 = 3; + 3 = 6) etc

Tags: java, counter

I'm not sure if this is possible in Java. I just finished Python and I've taken a webdesign course, so my brain isn't synced with Java yet. 
I want it to be something like this

```
double yourInput = input.nextDouble();

double numCount = (numCount + yourInput);
```

For example, if I entered 2, 7, and 9 (it would loop) I would want it to do something like this: numCount = 0; then numCount = 0 + 2; then numCount = 2 + 7; then numCount = 9 + 9.

Is this possible in Java? If so, how?

Comment: Why not, you can. Try and comeback.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible. Please try this yourself first.

Comment: Yes. it can be done in Java. But you can't declare a variable and use it at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop using `input.hasNextDouble()`:

```
//give default value
double numCount = 0;

//while user is still giving input
while(input.hasNextDouble()) {
    //get input
    double yourInput = input.nextDouble();
    //add input
    numCount += yourInput; 
}

//output
System.out.println("total = " + numCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Algorithm CONTINOUS_COUNTER()
BEGIN
    DECLARE inputReader : java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    DECLARE numCount    : Double;

    SET numCount := 0.0; //Setting the default value to the counter;

    LOOP until inputReader.hasNextDouble() returns TRUE

        numCount := numCount + inputReader.nextDouble();

    END LOOP;

    print "Num count = " + numCount;

END;
```

Dear Katy, this is the logic you should use to develop this program. This is just an algorithm. I don't think it's good to post the real program here, since you are learning Java. Try to convert this algorithm to the Java code. Learn it. :)

Comment: `LOOP until inputReader.hasNextDouble() returns TRUE` ?  Really?

Comment: David, I already said, this is just an algorithm. The real logic is while(inputReader.hasNextDouble()) {} :)

Comment: Yes, but that's the OPPOSITE of what you wrote. Also, I'm not sure of the value of providing an answer in a completely new programming language, to the question "can this be done in Java".  Katy claims to be proficient in Python, so presumably is perfectly able to come up with the right algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class DoubleCounter {

private static double total = 0.0;



public static void run(){
    while(true){
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Total Count: "+ total+" add next double: ");
        try{
            double next = Double.parseDouble(input);
            total+=next;
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong input! You must get a valid number!");
            continue;
        }


        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DoubleCounter.run();

}
```

}

You define a class DoubleCounter with a static member total count.
This class has a run() method that infinitly loop and show ad InputDialog.
The input dialog alway return a string that we 'try' to parsed in a double.
If parsed without problem, we add the result to the total count.

The class has a main method that is the application entry point that 'statically' call run() method of DoubleCounter.

I suggest you to see how 'static' modifier work on class member (total) and on methods (run()).

Hope helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Katy, this is the real program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContinousCounter{
    public static void main(final String [] args){
        double  numCount        =  0.0;
        Scanner inputReader     =  new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the values : ");
        while(inputReader.hasNextDouble()){ numCount += inputReader.nextDouble();}

        System.out.printf("The value for numCount = %f",numCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: The "yourInput" variable is not at all needed here. So it's better to avoid it. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what I think you're saying here, you should be using a `while` loop. It is fairly simple, just think about how you want it to work. It will loop a block of code that adds the scanner's next line to a sum

```
double mySum = 0;

while(input.nextDouble() != 0){
    double myInput = input.nextDouble();
    mySum += myInput;
}
```

In the above loop, we are assuming that when the scanner's next line is 0 there are no more numbers to add, but that can be adjusted so that it stops at other times.

I can see that since you have completed a course in Python programming that you are able to come up with the logic for this and are only looking for convention or proper syntax, so let's explain how the above works:

1. A `while` loop will run as long as the statement you let it handle evaluates to true, if you want it to do something while false you can put use an exclamation point before your statement and encase your parameters in parentheses such as the following : 
   `while (!(x<=2))`
   A while loop has the following syntax (in logical form):
   `while (boolean) {run this code}`
2. You can use the shorthand for adding `myInput` to your `mySum`:
   `+=` will add the righthand side to the lefthand side and save that value
3. If you want to run the code at least once despite the value, you can use a `do while` loop. The logic behind it is:
    `do {this} while (boolean);`